# Prove K(sub a), (sub b) is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

Here's the question from my homework: (1) "Let *a* and *b* be positive integers.  Define a graph as follows: $K_a$,$_b$ = (*V, E*), where *V* can be partitioned into two disjoint sets of size *a* and *b*.  That is, *V*=*A* $\cup$ *B*, where |*A*| = *a*, |*B*| = *b*, and *A* $\cap$ *B* = $\emptyset$.  The edge set is

E = { { *u* , *v* } : (*u* $\in$ *A* $\land$ *v* $\in$ *B* }

That is, the graph contains every edge from an element of *A* to an element of *B*, but no edges between two elements of *A* or two elements of *B*.

The first question (a) says: "Prove: $K_a$,$_b$ is connected.

The second question (b) says: Find and prove a necessary and sufficient condition on *a* and *b* for $K_a$,$_b$ to be a tree.

For the first question, all I know so far to say is: "In order for $K_a$,$_b$ to be connected, there must be only one component and at least one edge."
Any help or suggestions on where to go from here would be appreciated.

As for the second question I think I've found an answer, but in case it's related to the answer for part *a* I figured I'd include it in writing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), $K_{a,b}$ is connected if there exists a path between any two vertices $u$ and $v$ of $K_{a,b}$. Clearly if $u$ belongs to $A$ and $v$ belongs to $B$, they are connected by the edge $uv$. So consider $u$ and $v$ in the same component. Can you find a path between them?

For part (b), $K_{a,b}$ is a tree if it is connected and has no cycles. We've shown that it's connected. Under what conditions will no cycle exist in $K_{a,b}$?